# open jquery-ui dialog based on ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to open a jquery-ui dialog when the response of checklatestnews.php meets the condition rec != "0". I created a test checklatestnews.php file where the response is always "1", yet a jquery-ui dialog will still not open. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="dialog">

<script type="text/javascript">

 $("#dialog").dialog(
   {
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 100,
    modal: true
   }
);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var check_latestnews;
function CheckForLatestNewsNow() {
    var str="chklatestnews=true";
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checklatestnews.php",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            success: function(res){
                if(res != "0") {


 $("#dialog").html(response).dialog("open");

                }

            }
    });
}
check_latestnews = setInterval(CheckForLatestNewsNow, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post("checklatesnews.php", {action: "check"}, function(response) {
    .....
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: $("#dialog").dialog("open");
 is opening a blank dialogue but works. how do i echo the .html(data);

Comment: Then set data before open: `$("#dialog").html(data).dialog("open")`

Comment: I changed     $("#dialog").dialog("open"); to $("#dialog").html(data).dialog("open"); but now the dialogue is not opening

Comment: Check the `data` variable... What it contain? From where you get data? `console.log(data)`

Comment: If you get data from response and response type is json, then `$("#dialog").html(response.data).dialog("open");`

Comment: the response is not in json or xml format. it is simply whatever php echos

Comment: OK, then write response as is: `$("#dialog").html(response).dialog("open");`

Comment: I updated my code above. Not sure what's going on, but it's not working.

Comment: Close dialog div tag and replace response by res or res by response.